# How to send updates of item to database in DotNetNuke Module?

Tags: c#, sql, dotnetnuke

I am new to DotNetNuke and I am creating a new module and I am trying to figure out what the best way to upload data in database is.

I used this code:

```
public void UpdateStudentByID(int studentID, Student student)
{
    using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
    {
        var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Student>();
        rep.Update(student);
    }
}
```

But the problem is it didn't update anything in the database and when I checked the SQL profile I found it generated this query:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [Attendance_Students] SET [Surname] = @0, [GivenNames] = @1, [Birthdate] = @2, [Gender] = @3, [Address1] = @4, [Address2] = @5, [State] = @6, [PostCode] = @7, [Notes] = @8, [CreatedByUserId] = @9, [LastModifiedOnDate] = @10 WHERE [StudentId] = @11',N'@0 nvarchar(4000),@1 nvarchar(4000),@2 datetime,@3 nvarchar(4000),@4 nvarchar(4000),@5 nvarchar(4000),@6 nvarchar(4000),@7 nvarchar(4000),@8 nvarchar(4000),@9 int,@10 datetime,@11 int',@0=N'Good',@1=N'Good',@2='2013-02-20 00:00:00',@3=N'Male',@4=N'dsfdfsdfdf',@5=N'',@6=N'SA',@7=N'',@8=N'good',@9=1,@10='2013-02-15 02:58:39.047',@11=0
```

It's obvious from the query there is no where condition produced to update specific item.

So what is the best way to update the object into the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing in a Student object which doesn't have its StudentId property set to a value -- that's why your where criteria is trying to update where studentid = 0.  Set the value before calling the function and you should be good to go.

And by doing this, you won't need to call UpdateStudentByID passing both studentId and student, but rather just call UpdateStudent and pass student.

```
...
//Before calling UpdateStudent, make sure your StudentId property is set
student.StudentId = 123;
....

public void UpdateStudent(Student student)
{
    using (IDataContext ctx = DataContext.Instance())
    {
        var rep = ctx.GetRepository<Student>();
        rep.Update(student);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.